# Trying to use the aggregate sum function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, analytics

I have a dataframe and I'm trying to group it by TERRORIST & DATE and then run an aggregate sum function on the 2 remaining columns FATALITIES & INJURED. The problem is when i run the code it doesnt add the numbers it simply concatenates them.

For example, here is my code:

```
df_3 = df_2.groupby(by=['TERRORIST','DATE']).agg({'FATALITIES': 'sum',
                          'INJURED': 'sum'})
```

and it returns a list of digits like 1441133111111111222142

I believe this is happening because it is treating the data in my fatalities & injured columns as strings as opposed to integers. but when i do the following

```
def clean_2(row):
    fatalities = row['FATALITIES']
    injured = row['INJURED']
    fatalities = pd.to_numeric(df_2['FATALITIES'])
    injured = pd.to_numeric(df_2['INJURED'])
    return pd.Series([fatalities, injured])

df_2[['FATALITIES', 'INJURED']] = df_2.apply(clean_2, axis=1)

df_3 = df_2.groupby(by=['TERRORIST','DATE']).agg({'FATALITIES': 'sum',
                          'INJURED': 'sum'})
```

I get the following traceback:

```
ValueError: Function does not reduce
```

does anyone know what i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert the columns to numeric, rather than element-wise:

```
df_2['FATALITIES'] = pd.to_numeric(df_2['FATALITIES'])
df_2['INJURED'] = pd.to_numeric(df_2['INJURED'])

df_3 = df_2.groupby(by=['TERRORIST','DATE']).agg({'FATALITIES': 'sum', 'INJURED': 'sum'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function to convert to numeric seems too complicated, have you tried something like just:

`df_2['FATALITIES'] = df_2['FATALITIES'].astype(int)`

You can do this for the `INJURED` column as well, and if you get no errors then the groupby operations should work.